# How can I filter the data like this?

Tags: r, filter

I want to filter out data that is not from 2009 to 2018, how can I do it?

[image]

Here is my code

```
coffee_a <- coffee_ratings %>%
  filter(harvest_year_a <= 2018&!is.na(harvest_year)) %>%
  select("total_cup_points","harvest_year","variety","processing_method")

coffee_a%>%
  ggplot(coffee_a, mapping = aes(x = harvest_year_a, y = total_cup_points, color = processing_method)) +
  ylim(55,95) +
  geom_point(size = 0.08)
```

it always told me that they can't find "harvest_year_a".

```
dput(coffee_ratings)
structure(list(harvest_year = c("2014", "2014", NA, "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2012", "March 2010", "March 2010", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "Sept 2009 - April 2010", "March 2010", "2014", "May-August", 
"2009/2010", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2014", 
"2013", "2011", "2009/2010", "2013", "2016", "2015", NA, "2012", 
"2011", "2015/2016", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2010", "2009/2010", 
"2014", "2012", "2010", "2010", "2015", "2014", "2011", "2014", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2009/2010", "Fall 2009", "2016", "2013", 
"2013", "2017", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2017", "2013", "2012", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2013", 
"2015", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2009 / 2010", "2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2009/2010", "2009/2010", "2016", 
"2015", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2012", "2010-2011", "2010", NA, "2016", "2016", "2016", "2015", 
"2015", "2012", "2012", "2010-2011", NA, "2009/2010", "2016", 
"2015", "2015", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", "2009-2010", 
"2016", "2013", "2012", "2009/2010", "2009/2010", "2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2010-2011", "2009 - 2010", "2016", "2016", NA, "2015", 
"2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2013/2014", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2009/2010", 
NA, "2016", "2016", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", "2017 / 2018", "2016", 
"2015", "2014", "2015/2016", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "mmm", "TEST", "2016", "2017", "2015/2016", "2014", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2009/2010", "2017 / 2018", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2015", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2011", NA, "December 2009-March 2010", 
"2016", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015/2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2017", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014/2015", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2017", "2017 / 2018", "2016", "2016", "2014", 
"2014", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2015", 
"2014/2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", 
"2013/2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", 
"2017 / 2018", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2015", "2016", "2016", 
"2014", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2015/2016", 
"2014", "2014", "2014/2015", "2013", "2014", "2013/2014", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2011/2012", "2011", "2011", 
"2010", NA, "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015/2016", 
"2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "January 2011", "4T/10", NA, "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2015", NA, "2014", "2014/2015", "2014", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", NA, "2017 / 2018", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013/2014", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2016", "2016 / 2017", "2015", "2016", 
"2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", 
"2014", "2014/2015", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "23 July 2010", "2017 / 2018", "2017", 
"2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2014/2015", "2013", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", 
NA, "2010", NA, "January Through April", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2015/2016", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2013", "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
NA, NA, "2017", "2016", "2015", "2016", "2015", "2016", "2015/2016", 
"2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "1T/2011", "4t/2010", 
"4T/2010", "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2016", 
"2016", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2014/2015", "2014", 
"2013", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", "2010-2011", 
"August to December", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015/2016", "2015", 
"2015", "2014/2015", "2014", "2013", "2013/2014", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "Mayo a Julio", "47/2010", "2010", NA, "2017 / 2018", 
"2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2013", "2013/2014", 
"2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", "Abril - Julio", 
NA, NA, "4t/2011", "2009-2010", NA, "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2017", 
"2016", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2014/2015", 
"2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "Abril - Julio /2011", 
NA, "2017", "2017", "2015", "2016", "2015", "2014", "2015", "2015", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2010-2011", NA, "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2016", "2017", "2016", "2017", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2017 / 2018", 
"2016", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015/2016", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013/2014", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "Spring 2011 in Colombia.", 
NA, "2010-2011", "4T/10", "2009-2010", "2017", "2016", "2016", 
"2016 / 2017", "2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", 
"2013", "2014", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2011", "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2017", "2016", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013/2014", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
NA, "2017", "2017", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2016", "2015", "2016", 
"2015/2016", "2015/2016", "2013", "2014", "2012", "2013", "2013/2014", 
"2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", "3T/2011", 
"2017", "2016", "2016 / 2017", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015/2016", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014/2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
NA, "2016/2017", "2016", "2015/2016", "2014", "2015", "2014", 
"2014/2015", "2013/2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2016", 
"2015", NA, "2015", "2015/2016", "2015/2016", "2014", "2015", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013/2014", "2012", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "4T/10", "2017", "2016", 
"2016", "2015/2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "January 2011", 
"2017", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "Mayo a Julio", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2016 / 2017", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2013", "2014", 
"2012", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"4T/2010", "2017", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2015/2016", 
"2015/2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014/2015", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2011", "1t/2011", NA, "2017", "2014", 
"2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2011", 
"Mayo a Julio", "2017 / 2018", "2017", "2017", "2016", "2016", 
NA, "2016", "2015/2016", "2014", "2013", "2014/2015", "2013", 
"2014", "2013", "2014", "2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2018", "2017", 
"2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013/2014", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", NA, "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2013/2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "Abril - Julio", NA, "2017", 
"2016", "2015/2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014/2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2011", "4T72010", NA, 
"2016", "2016 / 2017", "2016", "2015/2016", "2015", "2014/2015", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2012", NA, "2015", "2015/2016", 
"2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2013/2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2016", "2015/2016", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2016", 
"2016", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2017", "2016 / 2017", "2016", "2016", 
"2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013/2014", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2015", 
"2014", "2014", "2014/2015", "2014", "2014/2015", "2013", "2014", 
"2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2012", NA, "2016", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "4T/2010", "2015/2016", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2012", 
"2012", "2011", "2016", "2015", "2015/2016", "2015", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", NA, "2016", "2016", "2014", 
"2014/2015", "2014", "2014", NA, NA, "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2016", "2015/2016", "2015", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2016", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2013/2014", "2012", 
"2012", "2016", "2015/2016", "2014", "2013/2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2012", "2010", "2017 / 2018", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2014", 
"2015", "2014", "2012", "2013/2014", "2012", "2012", "2017", 
"2015", "2015", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2017 / 2018", 
"2014", "2013", "2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2013/2014", "2012", 
"2012", "2017", "2015", "2014", "2013/2014", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2010", "2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", NA, "2017", "2017", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2016", 
"2014", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2016", "2016", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", NA, "2012", "2012", "4T/10", "2009/2010", 
"2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2012", 
"2016", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2014", "2012", "2017", 
"2017", "2016", "2015", "2012", "2012", "2012", "08/09 crop", 
"2017", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", NA, "2014", "2014", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2016", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2012", "2016", "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2012", "2012", NA, "2014", "2012", "2012", "2014/2015", 
"2012", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2014", "2012", 
"2016", "2012", "2016", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", NA, "2014", "2012", "2012", "2016", "2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2013", "2012", "2013", "2017 / 2018", "2014", "2012", "2013", 
"2013", "2012", "2014", "2016", "08/09 crop", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2011/2012", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2012", 
"2014", "2012", "2017 / 2018", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2016", "2014", 
"2014", "2013", "2014", "2010", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2014", 
"2017 / 2018", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2012", "2012", "2016", 
"2012", "2017", "2013", "2017", "2015", "2013", "2013", "2012", 
"2014", "2017", "2015", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2014", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2013", 
"2012", "2016", "2016", "2014", "2013", "2013")), row.names = c(NA, 
-1339L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: please share your data by adding to your question the output of `dput(coffee_ratings)`

Comment: Sorry I am not very good at using this, I don't quite understand how to share my data.:(

Comment: as I said, write in your console `dput(cofee_ratings)`. Copy what comes out and paste it at the end of your question. :-)

Comment: oh I get it, but the output is too much, I can't paste all of them behind my question.

Comment: then just select part of your data where the issue still appears (be sure the issue is still there with the selection!). For example `dput(head(cofee_ratings))`

Comment: oh yeah I made it!!!

Comment: I don't see any column named `harvest_year_a`

Comment: because I did not filter it properly:( and i don't know how to filter it.

Comment: try `filter(grepl(paste(2009:2018, collapse = "|"),harvest_year))`

Comment: then how do I named the new data set

Comment: thank you for your help and I have solved the problem :D